# formatting text in Flex

Tags: mysql, apache-flex

basically I have an admin flex page that allows the user to enter text into database. Then the frontend app will take the database entries and display them to the user.

However there is no formatting. Do I need to insert html into the database then read that html again?

For the user using the admin, they probably wont know html, so is there a simpler way to format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Rich Text Editor control fits your needs:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_10.html

Comment: Thanks.I guess the Textboxes can handle the html when coming back?